# How do I cache requests in React Query during page transitions?

Tags: next.js, react-query

I'm fetching data on the server side in Next.js using `getServerSideProps`. However, when I go from Page A to Page B, I notice that the same request (having the same `queryKey`) is fetched again. Is the API response supposed to be used from the cache since I have set `staleTime` to `Infinity`?

Here's a sample `getServerSideProps`:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  await queryClient.fetchQuery({
    queryKey: ['posts'],
    queryFn: () => fetchPosts(), // This is a simple function to fetch posts from an API.
    staleTime: Infinity,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  };
}
```

Let's assume that the same `getServerSideProps` also exists for Page B. When I go from Page A to Page B or vice versa, I expect React Query to use the data for the `queryKey: ['posts']` from the cache instead of fetching again on every page change.